# An address value change is not reflected in the while loop

Tags: c, algorithm, synchronization

I am given the code of standard Dekker algorithm by my professor that I need to test on NachOS by implementing algorithms of our own. But I have spotted one hopeful mistake in my professor's code. Here is a snippet of the Dekker's code that he has provided us with:

```
void DekkerEntry (int *flag, int id, int *turn)
{
   flag[id] = 1;
   while (flag[1-id]) {
       if ((*turn) == (1-id)) {
         flag[id] = 0;
         while ((*turn) == (1-id));  // mark this while loop
         flag[id] = 1;
       }
   }
}
```

There are other tests related to shared memory implementation that our code works well enough. But this one goes into an infinite loop. But to my surprise, it doesn't go into an infinite loop and gives the correct answer if I change the marked while loop to just include a print statement!

```
while ((*turn) == (1-id)){syscall_wrapper_PrintString("hello");}
```

I think the mistake is not taking a `volatile` type as `turn` and passing it as a pointer thinking its change will be reflected in the while loop. The smart compiler according to me doesn't check that condition since the while loop is emtpy, and uses a pre stored `turn`'s address value.

But is it true that pointers have this problem as well? I know simple variables do have this problem in while loops since there the compiler may assume their value doesn't change in the loop. I am confused why by adding only a print statement the algorithm works correctly and else not. Am I thinking right? Would love to know what is your view into this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `while ((*turn) == (1-id));`  This loops forever if the condition is `true`.  Note the semicolon at the end.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is intended as a busy wait. It's awful for many, many reasons, but it's what is intended.

Comment: By the way, for just one reason why nobody should ever use code even remotely like this on any actual computer, consider if the thread executing that busy wait and the thread it is waiting for happen to share a physical core. The busy wait will monopolize core resources and slow down the very thread it's waiting for. Also, consider the horrible mispredicted branch penalty when the busy wait loop finally ends -- slowing you to a crawl at the worst possible time.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you please elaborate on your point?

Comment: @Akash -- Don't know how much simpler to explain it.  Unless that condition turns into a `false` condition, the `while` loop is infinite.  `while(true);`  When will `true` be turned into `false`?  It will never be `false`, thus the loop will never terminate.  This is equivalent to `while(true) { }`

Comment: But `turn` is a pointer, right? That's what my doubt is. If there would have been `while(k == 1);` I know that would have been in an infinite loop for a similar case. But is the condition same with pointers? What is a turn around for this? @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Probably another thread has to change the value of `*turn` to not equal `1 - id`.  That's the only way that `while` loop makes sense, sense meaning the loop will terminate at some point.

Comment: There are two threads, trying to change the address value pointed by `turn`. Yet, I am getting an infinite loop. Is that possible? Or something wrong in my implementation side? That's basically my query. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Like David exclaimed, it is actually a busy wait. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @Akash: The problem with that logic is that C++ doesn't support busy waits on a `int` value. You'd need an `std::atomic<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

The `volatile` keyword has no guaranteed effects on multi-threaded code in C++. Instead, you need some way to perform operations on `turn` that have memory-visibility guarantees. It's possible that on your particular platform, that is the `volatile` keyword. But since you don't specify what threading standard of platform you are using, there's no way we could know. If it's just C++ threading, then `volatile` is of no help and you need to use C++'s memory-visibility features through atomics.

Comment: It's C threading. And we are implementing NachOS that means they are user threads.

Comment: @Akash I'm not familiar enough with threading on NachOS to comment usefully on what threading semantics `volatile` has on that platform. But if the platform threading documentation says you can rely on `volatile` for that purpose, then you can. If not, then not.

Comment: @Akash: If it's C, please don't use the C++ tag.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with my professor himself, I was sure there was some implementation problem on my side. Please note that a pointer address value will be always be checked alike volatile variables for the problem in hand (memory visibility changes in loops). Thus there is absolutely no problem with pointers in while loop condition.

For learning the actual problem :

The actual problem was that I was running the algorithm mistakenly only for non-preemptive context switches. When I switched to pre-emptive context switches as well, I got it working. The working of the code for non-preemptive (asked in question by adding a print statement) is that it was I/O operation and hence it was only getting switched out on non pre-emptive context switches that allowed the change of loop variables to a certain extent but ultimately hanging in a deadlock.

Comment: "*Please note that a pointer address value will be always be checked alike volatile variables. Thus there is absolutely no problem with pointers in while loop condition.*" If this is correct, it's a NachOS platform thing. It's *definitely* not true in general for C or C++.

Comment: Certainly @DavidSchwartz . More specifically, I was talking about the condition in loops that may not be memory visible, but are in case of pointers in C, C++. NachOS is implemented in C. I have edited the answer. Thanks for pointing that out. It is indeed not true in general.

Comment: They are not in the the case of pointers in C or C++. If this is true in NachOS, it's because NachOS specifically says so. It is *not* true generally of C or C++ which don't provide memory visibility guarantees whether through pointers or not.

Comment: It worked in my case. So do you mean, it depends upon the compiler when to look upon a change and when to ignore in case of pointer as well, just like normal variables? Can you provide an explanation or a counter example?

Comment: @Akash: The problem is that a compiler **may** notice there's nothing in the loop that can change the pointed-to variable. Your incorrect assumption is that other threads may change that value, but C requires thread synchronization. A compiler which sees that thread synchronization **does** know that pointed-to variables can change.

Comment: @MSalters can you elaborate on the part: `A compiler which sees that thread synchronization does know that pointed-to variables can change` ?  For instance, if I use a function from an external library to do the thread synchronization (let's call it: fjardon_mutex_lock/unlock), will or will not the compiler be aware of the synchronization ? Given that at compilation time the compiler doesn't know the content of this function (which may be an empty function or a wrapper around pthread_xxx).

Comment: @MSalters That clears things up a bit. The fun fact is that you don't need thread synchronization in this case. Dekker's algorithm being implemented here is actually a _soft_ lock to a critical section of a code :P Also if you can help with editing my answer so that I can accept it and not the current wrong one, it will be great help for all of us. Thanks!

Comment: @fjardon: The compiler can't make assumptions about code which isn't visible, but it can check the code that is visible. The code _writing_ to `*turn` might be protected by `fjardon_mutex_lock`, but as the read above isn't protected by `fjardon_mutex_lock` it's still unsafe. A mutex needs to protect both sides.

Comment: @MSalters So if I wrap pthread_mutex_lock/unlock inside functions and use these functions the compiler can assume the pointed to variable is not modified ? and my code will not run correctly even though I correctly used pthread locks ?

Comment: @fjardon: No, if you prefix **both** reads and writes with non-inlined calls to `fjardon_mutex_lock`, the compiler must play it safe.

Comment: @Akash Neither the C standard nor the C++ standard say what should or must happen if one thread tries to access an object while another thread is, or might be, modifying it. So the compiler is free to make code that does terrible things if you do this. Fortunately, every sensible standard or platform that supports threads provides some way for you to do this. You just have to check your documentation to find out the supports ways to do this and pick one. If the documentation says `volatile` will work, then it will. If it says you don't need it, then you don't. But it's not a C/C++ issue.

Comment: @Akash I should also add that most threading platforms provide locks and atomic operations. I know of no platform using C where the guarantee you seem to think you have is actually provided. That doesn't mean one doesn't exist, it would just be an extreme outlier. Most compilers optimize out pointer references all the time. Relying on the compiler not to be smart enough to make an optimization that is legal but will break your code is a *bad* idea.